# Cannot launch inkscape and w3m with same error message "Wrong __data_start/_end pair"

Tags: inkscape, w3m

On Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64, I cannot launch inkscape due to the following error message.

```
% inkscape
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
[1]    XXXX abort      inkscape
```

The same issue arises with w3m.

```
% w3m
Wrong __data_start/_end pair
[1]    XXXX abort      w3m
```

I tried the reinstallation ("apt purge inkscape && apt install inkscape") but still see the same error message.
How can I resolve this issue?

---

I found a solution by myself.
The zsh built-in command "unlimit" written in my .zshrc was the cause of this issue.
Removing "unlimit" from .zshrc, inkscape and w3m can be launched normally now.
Strictly speaking, "unlimit stacksize" seems to be the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for this!  You might want to answer your own question and accept it.  It is correct and it certainly helped me.  I'm a bash user and when I did `ulimit -a`, my stack size was set to unlimited.  I changed it with `ulimit -s <amount of memory in kbytes on my computer>` and then it ran correctly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questioner solved their own question:

> I found a solution by myself. The zsh built-in command "unlimit" written in my .zshrc was the cause of this issue. Removing "unlimit" from .zshrc, inkscape and w3m can be launched normally now. Strictly speaking, "unlimit stacksize" seems to be the root cause.