# w3m fails to launch with Wrong __data_start/_end pair

Tags: w3m

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64`. The program [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) fails to launch as follows:

```
$ w3m -h

Wrong __data_start/_end pair
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried

- installing and reinstalling;
- setting a stack-size bound with `ulimit`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142308/cannot-launch-inkscape-and-w3m-with-same-error-message-wrong-data-start-end).

No luck.

The issue also came up in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254765/error-message-wrong-data-start-end-pair-while-using-mpb-in-ubuntu-20-04-win), but that is specific to the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which I am not on.

**Edit**

Getting closer: this is a kernel issue.

The machine is running a custom-compiled [kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux), currently at `v5.17-rc3`. If I go back to version `5.16` of the kernel I do *not* see the issue.

I'm not sure how things have changed for the `5.17` release, but it seems some modification to the kernel config is needed.

**Edit 2**

Found [something promising](https://lkml.kernel.org/lkml/CALjTZvZiEOtVcpTm+fgAvCB6T88GzbGEZcdrQ77MLD7hJnnJ9w@mail.gmail.com/T/) on the kernel mailing list.

I have yet to test that patch, but it fits with what I'm seeing: the problem appearing after `v5.17-rc1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second edit has all I need: it was a kernel issue, due to the fact that I'm not running the standard `Ubuntu` version.

Compiling the [latest version](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) of the kernel (still `v5.17-rc3` as I write this) with the patch provided [here](https://lkml.kernel.org/lkml/CALjTZvZiEOtVcpTm+fgAvCB6T88GzbGEZcdrQ77MLD7hJnnJ9w@mail.gmail.com/T/) resolves the matter.

So I expect that by the time `Linux 5.17` makes its way into the `Ubuntu` repos this will have been fixed upstream. In short, I'm all set.

Answer (score 0):

I am the user who posted the `+50` bounty.  In my particular use case, `w3m` is activated through `Emacs`.  The custom build of `Emacs` that I use requires a high `ulimit` setting for a particular undo/redo history library that I am rather fond of.  I had been launching `Emacs` with a desktop file containing:

```
Exec=bash -c 'ulimit -S -s unlimited && /path/to/emacs'
```

The problem is `unlimited`.  The solution is to use a set amount that is somewhat less than the system limit, in `kB`.  From the terminal, type `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` and the result looks something like this:

```
MemTotal:        8141092 kB
```

So, the change now looks like this:

```
Exec=bash -c 'ulimit -S -s 8000000 && /path/to/emacs'
```